# Instantiating a class in an async fastapi "startup" function and importing it from other modules

Tags: python, async-await, fastapi

I have a fastapi program:

```
app
├── src
│   ├── router
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── api_router.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mymodule.py
│   __init__.py
│   main.py
```

main.py looks like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from src.router import api_router

from big_model_loader import load_big_model

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(api_router, prefix='/api')


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    """
    code here will be run on app start
    """
    await init_middlewares(app)
    
    global big_model; big_model = load_big_model('filename')
```

I want to instantiate big_model at startup, only once, because it's a big model, and import the instance in mymodule.py

Is there a better solution than `global big_model`?

Comment: If you want ``big_model`` in global scope, ``global big_model`` seems perfectly fine.

Comment: In the FastAPI examples for the `startup` event they use an dict outside of the function that is populated with values; https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event - that being said, you could probably just load it directly in the the code above the `startup_event` handler if you control the app initialization directly in your code anyway.